# Django get app name from file

Tags: python, django

I need to execute some custom raw SQL in Django (1.9). Since tables in Django are prefixed with the app name I need to retrieve the app name. I want to use the same code in different apps later on, so I would like to get the app name in a soft coded way, just given the file the code resides in. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of "guessing" the table name using the default convention you should use `Model.objects.model._meta.db_table` to get the real name.

A model can override the default table name convention and this will break your code reusability...

Comment: `Model.objects.model` is just a reference to `Model`. You can use `Model._meta.db_table`.

Comment: Great point! Would you suggest something as simple as `Model._meta.db_table.split('_')[0]` to retrieve the prefix?

Comment: @jarno don't do that, it will break if `db_table` has been changed to something without an underscore. If you want the app name, use [`MyModel._meta.app_label`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#app-label)

Comment: Now that was exactly what I was looking for!